# How to check if website link has data (picture) or website is invalid?

Tags: java, android

I want to test if website has data in it or it's invalid link in android studio. For example:

Has data:

https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-o/03/d8/a8/70/zinfandel-s.jpg

Has no data cause link is invalid:

https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/po/03/d8/a8/70/zdel-s.jpg

Answer (score 1):

We can also use java.net.url class to validate a URL. A MalformedURLExceptio will be thrown if no protocol is specified, or an unknown protocol is found, or spec is null. Then we will call method toURI()that will throw a URISyntaxException if the URL cannot be converted to URI

```
class URLValidator {
    public static boolean urlValidator(String url) {
        try {
            new URL(url).toURI();
            return true;
        }
        catch (URISyntaxException exception) {
            return false;
        }

        catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String url = "https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/po/03/d8/a8/70/zdel-s.jpg"; 
        if (urlValidator(url)) 
            System.out.print("The given URL: " + url + " , contain image.");
        else
            System.out.print("The given URL: " + url + " , is not contain image.");        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you can use okhttp library for maing http-requests.
here's the snippet for you:

```
  private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
  public void run() throws Exception {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/po/03/d8/a8/70/zdel-s.jpg")
        .build();

    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
      if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
        //this will run if image is not available 
      }
    }
  }
```